# Codegnither captcha image is not displaying

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, captcha

I truly surfed around the net and even similar questioned has posted in this forum but I found most of them are not yet answered.

Anyway I thought to post my issue also here, If any one could help ASAP I would really appreciated it.

I doing this in localhost and here is my controller,

```
   public function register(){

            $this->load->helper('captcha');

            $captcha = array(
                'word' => 'Random 123',
                'imag_path' => './captcha/',
                'img_url' => base_url() . 'captcha/',
                'font_path' => './fonts/arial.ttf',
                'img_width' => '300',
                'img_height' => '50',
                'expiration' => '3600',
            );
            print_r($captcha);
            $img = create_captcha($captcha);
            $data['image'] = $img['image'];

            if(!$_POST){
            $this->load->view('public/register', $data);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

My view has following script,

```
<?php
    echo $image;
?>
```

Issue : Captcha image is not displaying

FYI: In my research I found many people mentioned first consider following points.

1) Check "captcha" folder is 777 mode

2) check GD Library is loaded

I did check above points but I'm not 100% sure because I cannot see folder permission is set to 777 in locally (I'm using windows 7 32bit). When right click and check the "captcha" folder properties it's set to

Attributes 
      Read only (checked)
      Hidden (unchecked)

Is this correct? if so then do you have any idea why my Captcha image is not working?

Let me know if you need further details?

Comment: make a folder named `captcha` and then use `base_ulr()` to img_path

Comment: I already have captcha and font folder inside the application folder. I even checked adding captcha folder one level up also but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code

```
<?php 

    $pool = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $captcha = substr( str_shuffle( $pool ), 0, 5 );  


   $vals = array(
                'word' => $captcha,
    'img_path'   => 'front_images/captcha/',
    'img_url'    => base_url().'front_images/captcha/',
    'img_width'  => 120,
    'img_height' => 35,
    'font_path' => './system/fonts/texb.ttf',
    'expiration' => 3600 //1 houre
  );

  $cap = create_captcha($vals);
  echo $cap['image']

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but still the result is same captcha image is not displaying. I even created the **front_images** folder as follow
application
front_image/captcha/

Comment: sorry i forgot to include the `helper`. you include it?

Comment: captcha helper? if so then yes added as **$this->load->helper('captcha');**

Answer (score 0):

You have a mis typing in your config array, instead of `imag_path` its `img_path`. 
Also make sure about the following things:

```
1. `img_path` or `img_url` is set properly.
2. If you have specified `img_path`, then make sure such a directory exists.
3. Make sure the `img_path` is `writable`.
4. Make sure `gd` library is installed.
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing the error. however I tried @Azam Alvi example it didn't work. Also could you please confirm how to check, Is GD library is installed or not?